# Dynamic search panel in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a panel with information. I want to have in this panel a search input field in which the users can type, and as soon as a matched word, that word would be highlighted in that panel and the rest of the information vanish.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link
[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)